# How to compile ipopt with BLIS and libFLAME on Windows with MinGW or/and cygwin

Tags: windows, lapack, amd-processor, ipopt

Related to my other question, I was trying to compile ipopt with the BLIS and libFLAME library, but am still struggling to get this set up correctly. Since there are many different sources of information, I will provide a full history of what I've tried so far. The main sources I refer to are the ipopt installation instructions [ipopt install](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL.html) and the official documentation of the AMD Optimizing CPU Libraries [(AOCL)](https://developer.amd.com/amd-aocl/#documentation).

As I am running Windows10, I installed the recommended MSYS2/MINGW for the compilation process:

- Ran a fresh install of MSYS2/MINGW with default settings
- Updated with `pacman -Syu`
- Ran `pacman -Su`
- Installed the toolchain as suggested with `pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`

From here, I follow the ipopt installation guide:

- `pacman -S binutils diffutils git grep make patch` Note that I did not load pkg-conf since this kinda raises conflicts with pkgconf
- `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran`
- `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-lapack mingw-w64-x86_64-metis`

From here, I start with BLIS installation:

- `git clone https://github.com/amd/blis.git` According to the official AOCL documentation, this is the correct repository, I guess?
- `./configure --prefix="C:/msys64/mingw64" --enable-cblas --enable-threading=openmp zen2`
- When calling `make` now I get an error

```html
include/zen2/blis.h:47148:13: error: conflicting types for 'pid_t'; have 'int'
47148 | typedef int pid_t;
      |             ^~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

which is probably related to the `sys/types.h` header file not available for MINGW?
When I do the same configuration with the repository [flame/blis](https://github.com/flame/blis), it compiles just fine.
This is the output of the `make install`:

```html
$ make install
Installing libblis.a into C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/
Installing libblis.dll.a into C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/
Installing libblis.4.dll into C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/
Generating monolithic cblas.h........
Generated include/zen2/cblas.h
Installing blis.h cblas.h into C:/msys64/mingw64/include/blis/
Installing config.mk common.mk into C:/msys64/mingw64/share/blis/
Installing config/zen2/make_defs.mk into C:/msys64/mingw64/share/blis/config/zen2
mkdir -p C:/msys64/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
Installing blis.pc into C:/msys64/mingw64/share/pkgconfig/
install -c -m 0644 blis.pc C:/msys64/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
```

And `pkgconf blis --libs` gives me `-LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lblis`

Next comes the installation of libFLAME:

- According to official AOCL documentation `git clone https://github.com/amd/libflame.git`
- `./configure --prefix="C:/msys64/mingw64" --enable-windows-build --enable-multithreading=openmp --enable-cblas-interfaces --enable-lapack2flame`
- Invoking `make` leads me into the error

```html
src/map/lapack2flamec/f2c/install/util/abs.c:30:9: error: unknown type name '_Fcomplex'; did you mean 'complex'?
   30 |         _Fcomplex z_ = {z->r, z->i};
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
      |         complex
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
make: *** [Makefile:554: obj/x86_64-w64-mingw32/src/map/lapack2flamec/f2c/install/util/abs.o] Error 1
```

This error can be avoided by omitting the lapack2flame option in the configuration, but it will just result in another error

```html
src/base/flamec/wrappers/base/wrapper/libflame_api_wrapper.h:7413:12: error: conflicting types for 'sisnan'; have 'int(const float *)'
 7413 | extern int sisnan(const float  *sin);
      |            ^~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Maybe they are also both related to the `sys/types.h` header file? Or am I doing it completely wrong? Again, trying the same configuration with the alternative repository [flame/libflame](https://github.com/flame/libflame) yields another error

```html
src/map/lapack2flamec/f2c/install/static/dsecnd.c:2:10: fatal error: sys/times.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <sys/times.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

related to the `sys/times.h` header file not available on MSYS. Omitting the lapack2flame option actually yields a successful compilation, wow. I also tried compiling with cygwin with the lapack2flame option, since cygwin offers support for the sys header files and it compiled successfully, however, since I do not know how the compiled library works with different compilation by msys and cygwin (e.g. used gcc libraries, yes, I don't know anything about static or dynamic library structures and the whole building process..), I decided to continue with the generated library by MINGW.

```html
$ make install
Installing libflame.a into C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/
Installing FLAME.h into C:/msys64/mingw64/include/
```

libFLAME does not generate a package config file. There is a pull request [#50](https://github.com/flame/libflame/pull/50) addressing this.

Suppose, libflame has been setup successfully, it is located in the ordinary library folder and can be flagged with -lflame.

Back to the ipopt installation: As suggested, I use the ThirdParty repositories provided under [coin-or-tools](https://github.com/coin-or-tools).

- Compiled ASL library with `./configure ADD_CFLAGS=-fopenmp ADD_FFLAGS=-fopenmp ADD_CXXFLAGS=-fopenmp`, `make`, `make install`
- Cofigured HSL library with `./configure --with-lapack-lflags="-lflame -lblis" ADD_CFLAGS=-fopenmp ADD_FFLAGS=-fopenmp ADD_CXXFLAGS=-fopenmp` gives me another error:

```html
checking for LAPACK... configure: error: Cannot link to user-specified Lapack -lflame -lblis.
```

From the config.log, I can see that the error results from an ld reference:

```html
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccCcm9Lg.o:conftest.c:(.text.startup+0xa): undefined reference to `foobar'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But at this point, I have no idea how to resolve this. When using the standard lapack library and BLIS `./configure --with-lapack-lflags="-llapack -lblis" ADD_CFLAGS=-fopenmp ADD_FFLAGS=-fopenmp ADD_CXXFLAGS=-fopenmp` the compilation is successful, which makes me think that BLIS at least might be installed correctly.
Continuing with this configuration has worked to compile ipopt as well. However, when using linear solvers using multi-threading like MA77, MA86 or MA97, the performance is actually heavily reduced compared with openblas, for instance.

Some other things I tried:

- Tried to install the Windows libraries from the [AOCL](https://developer.amd.com/amd-aocl/#downloads) - this results in some .dll and .lib files and I could not figure out how to set the --with-lapack-lflags correctly in order to link them.
- Downloaded the Linux files from the AOCL and compiled them to a static library with cygwin - this gives the static libraries which I copied to the library directory of MINGW, but it resulted in the same error as with the -lflame configuration above.

Maybe someone who actually managed to get this running on Windows has some additional information how to proceed from here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The config.log error about "undefined reference to `foobar'" is probably not the one relevant for the Lapack test failing. configure does a number of check via compiler calls and not all of them need to succeed. So instead of the first, you better look for the last "error" in config.log.

Comment: The `--with-lapack-lflags` should point to the `.lib` file and you should make sure that the `.dll` can be found when executing a binary. I think their path needs to be in the `LIB` or `PATH` environment variables.